# DB relationship: implementing a conversation

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to implement a simple conversation feature, where each conversation has a set of messages between two users. My question is, if I have a reference from a message to a conversation, whether I should have a reference the other way as well.

Right now, each message has `conversationId`. To retrieve all the messages the belong to a certain conversation, I should do `Message.find({conversationId: ..})`. If I had stored an array of messages in a conversation object, I could do `conversation.messages`.

Which way is the convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on usage patterns. First, you normalize: 1 conversation has many messages, 1 message belongs to 1 conversation. That means you've got a 1-to-many (1:M) relationship between conversations and messages.

In a 1:M relationship, the SQL standard is to assign the "1" as a foreign key to each of the "M". So, each message would have the conversationId.

In Mongo, you have the option of doing the opposite via arrays. Like you said, you could store an array of messageIds in the conversation. This gets pretty messy because for every new message, you have to edit the conversation doc. You're essentially doubling your writes to the DB & keeping the 2 writes in sync is completely on you (e.g. what if the user deletes a message & it's not deleted from the conversation?).

In Mongo, you also have to consider the difference between 1:M and 1:F (1-to-few). Many times, it's advantageous to nest 1:F relationships, ie make the "F" a subdoc of the "1". There is a limit: each doc cannot exceed 16MB (this may lift in future versions). The advantage of nesting subdocs is you have atomic transactions because it's all the same doc, not to mention subscriptions in a pub/sub are easier. This may work, but if you've got a group-chat with 20 friends that's been going on for the last 4 years, you might have to get clever (cap it, start a new conversation, etc.)

Nesting would be my recommendation, although your origin idea of assigning a conversationId to each message works too (make sure to index!).

Comment: Thanks. A quick followup -- so if I decide to nest messages under a conversation, I wouldn't need to store conversationId in a message document, right?

Comment: nope, the object will probably be nothing more than the content, datestamp, and hasRead boolean.